# UIToolbar in iPad

Tags: ipad

I wanted to  have two buttons on the both end of Navigation Bar (in iPad's Detail View Controller).

So I created two UIToolbars and I set the them as Left&RightBarButtonItems.

But, There is some color variation in the NavigationBar.

Attached images for your understanding.

[image]

[image]                                                 [image]

the code I used ,

```
 UIToolbar *leftToolbar =[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 45)];
 NSMutableArray *lItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[leftToolbar items]];
 UIBarButtonItem *lb1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(home:) ];

 UIBarButtonItem *lb2 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Document"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(newDoc:) ];

 [lItems insertObject:lb1 atIndex:0];
 [lItems insertObject:lb2 atIndex:1];
 [leftToolbar setItems:lItems animated:YES];
 [lItems release];



  leftToolbar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
 leftToolbar.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftToolbar];
```

Can you help me to avoid this color variation?

Is there any other way to have buttons like this, without using  UIToolbar?

Thanks ,

Gopi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove navigation bar and add tool bar, why you adding toolbar to navigation bar?

Comment: I need to show some documents, So I need to display the name of the document in the title of the Navigation bar.

Comment: How can i add titles in Toolbar? I believe I cant have Labels in toolbar. I couldnt find any other way to implement it. let me know if i miss something..Thanks GameBit.

Comment: here you have 2 choices: 1) just put UILabel on top 2) add UITabButton with plain style

Comment: UIBarButtonItem wtih plain style is a good one.Finally I have to use that if I dont find any. It glows when i tap on that. So thinking of finding some better way to do that.I have seen some apps that have the same format of my Top bar (as given in the above image) , and they dont glow when tapped. So there should be some other way that I am unaware of. UILabel can't be added in UIToolbar , I tried it already. Any suggestions on my views? Thanks GameBit.

Comment: why UILabel can't be added? just [_toolbar addSubview:...] and that's it (don't do it in IB).

Comment: Label is getting added. but not as a part of Toolbar.It is added separately .I tried to add it as an "item" in Toolbar, that landed in an error,"[UILabel view] unknown selector sent to. . .etc"

Comment: how come its not part of toolbar?    
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:[toolBar bounds]];
    [titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleLabel setText:@"My Title"];
    [toolBar addSubview:titleLabel];   
    [titleLabel release];

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same, use segment controll, set it in Left or right barbutton's view, once you select a segmet, deselect it after few seconds, say 0.3secs, it looks good, no color vairations, it looks like a part of Navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution !
 code is correct, but one small bug.  Have to set the height to 44, not 45.  I did this and it seems to fit over the existing NavigationBar.

```
UIToolbar *leftToolbar =[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
```

Works for me . .  Anyway I moved to the Single tool bar method.

Hope this helps some one.!!

Have a great day!!

Gopi.